# C++ regex character classes

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc4.8

Trying to create a `std::regex` object with a `[]`-enclosed character class in C++ I am getting an error:

```
std::regex re0("\\.");
std::regex re1("a");
std::regex re2("a+");
std::regex re3("a*");
std::regex re4("[az]");  // fails
std::regex re5("[a-z]");  // fails
```

This results in the following error:

```
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "regex_error"
```

I am using gcc version 4.8.2.

The syntax seems correct [according to the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/#character_classes) and works in other regex compilers (I tried Python's [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)). How can I create a regular expression object for a range character class in C++?

Comment: gcc 4.8.x is known to be buggy and incomplete regarding `std::regex` implementation. Use gcc 4.9.x instead please.

Comment: Although the duplicate question I've linked to asks about gcc4.7, the same applies to gcc4.8

Comment: @Praetorian good to know! Unfortunately, that article didn't show up in the SO search. I didn't expect the implementation of <regex> to be incomplete in the first place, rather than suspected a wrong usage on my part.